# Ansible random UUID generation

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible script, I want to generate UUIDs on the fly and use them later on.

Here is my approach:

```
- shell: echo uuidgen
  with_sequence: count=5
  register: uuid_list


  - uri: 
      url: http://www.myapi.com
      method: POST
      body: "{{ item.item.stdout }}"
    with_items: uuid_list.result
```

However I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'stdout'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In ansible 1.9 there is a new filter : to_uuid , which given a string it will return an ansible domain specific UUID,you can find the usage in here https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters

Comment: With the same input the results always the same, so you would need something like `{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro | to_uuid }}` to get a real uuid.

Comment: J0hnG4lt this approach won't produce a random uuid.

Comment: Yes. Remove that comment, bcz. you find this approach in some github ansible roles that people consider production-ready :D

Comment: The point of a UUID is not ONLY that it's randomized for security, but more importantly to ensure a unique ID across multiple servers regardless of where it's generated.  Yes, if security is an issue on a specific table / resource, then by all means randomize it using the spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122), otherwise, if all an admin is looking for is uniqueness, there is no problem with this.

Answer (score 19):

As metioned by Xingxing Gao, there is `to_uuid` which can be used with a large enough number and the `random` filter to produce a random UUID. The larger the number the greater the randomness. eg:

```
{{ 99999999 | random | to_uuid }}
```

or

```
{{ 9999999999999999999999 | random | to_uuid }}
```

Comment: Depending on what you need the UUID for, using something like `{{ inventory_hostname | to_uuid }}` is convenient when you want consistent unique UUIDs across multiple Ansible runs.

Answer (score 8):

Generate a random UUID from a 20 char string with upper/lower case letters and digits:

```
{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits') | to_uuid }}
```

Comment: Approved : that's really better than other solutions based on the *random* filter ; you can also just give the required length (and therefore entropy) as a parameter ; e.g. `lookup( 'password', '/dev/null length=32' ) | to_uuid`.

(`/dev/null` because we don't need to store the generated "password" in a file)

More [in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/password.html)

Answer (score 6):

This is very close. I only had to change a few things. I figured this out by using the task "`debug: var=uuid_list`" and iterating.

```
- shell: uuidgen                # note 1
  with_sequence: count=5
  register: uuid_list
- uri:
    url: http://www.myapi.com
    method: GET
    body: "{{ item.stdout }}"    # note 2
    timeout: 1                   # note 3
  with_items: uuid_list.results  # note 4
```

Notes:

1. `echo` caused the string `uuidgen` to be printed. removed `echo`, kept `uuidgen`.
2. `item.item.stdout` needed to be `item.stdout`
3. I used a short timeout so I could test this without having a rest endpoint available. This gives failure error messages but it's clear that it is correct.
4. `uuid_list.stdout` needed to be `uuid_list.results`

Answer (score 5):

Be aware if you use Willem's solution, Jinja and Ansible will cache the result for multiple executions of the same filter, so you must change the source number each time

```
  api_key_1: "{{ 999999999999999999995 | random | to_uuid }}"
  api_key_2: "{{ 999999999999999999994 | random | to_uuid }}"
```

and for situations where you need a normal md5 instead of to_uuid, hash('md5') does not take an integer. The most convenient way to convert the random to a string I've found is to use to_uuid:

```
  api_key_3: "{{ 999999999999999999999 | random | to_uuid | hash('md5') }}"
  api_key_4: "{{ 999999999999999999998 | random | to_uuid | hash('md5') }}"
```

Comment: While it may be generally true that Jinja caches the result of filters in the way you describe, it does not appear to be the case when used with Ansible. I've tried this technique to define a run-specific random variable and get different values for the placement of the same variable in different templates, for example. I'm using Ansible 2.3.0 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

One solution which should be immune to caching/stale fact gathering and give you a reasonably random UUID each time you use it is:

`{{ (999999999999999999999 | random | string + (lookup('pipe', 'date +%s%N'))) | to_uuid() }}`

It concatenates a random number between 0 and 999999999999999999999 with current nanoseconds since Unix epoch and feeds that through Ansible's to_uuid() filter (available since version 1.9). Fact caching should not cause a problem as lookups are always evaluated each and every time they are invoked.

If you want a UUID that remains constant throughout the plays in a playbook (but doesn't persist between multiple invocations of the playbook - even with fact caching turned on) then use:

`set_fact: uuid={{ (999999999999999999999 | random | string + (lookup('pipe', 'date +%s%N'))) | to_uuid() }}`

Comment: There are brackets missing around `9999....))` so it vomits the date concatenated to uuid instead of generating uuid from date+random number. `{{ (999999999999999999999 | random | string + ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro) | to_uuid() }}` works for me without this useless pipe lookup

Comment: @Misko the lookup is there to bust fact caching (I wasn't aware of ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro when I wrote this answer). Good catch on the brackets (will edit).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to avoid using the filter to_uuid, because it does not only take numbers as input but also characters. So, if I would only give it numbers as input, I would not be able to create every uuid possible.

I came up with this solution:

```
- name: Generate UUID
  vars:
    # This creates a random 128-bit integer and translates it to hexadecimal string.
    # Zeros are put infront of the hex string, to make it always 32 hex-digits long.
    __uuid: "{{ '%032x' % ((2**128) | random) }}"
    # Format the hexadecimal string to a UUID format: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    uuid: "{{ __uuid[0:8] }}-{{ __uuid[8:12] }}-{{ __uuid[12:16] }}-{{ __uuid[16:20] }}-{{ __uuid[20:32] }}"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ uuid }}"
```