# Maintaining Idempotence with the lineinfile and copy module

Tags: ansible

I am generating a file that contains a UUID in it using the copy or lineinfile modules. However, when running these playbooks a second time, the task reiterates over the existing line or file with the content.

```
- name: Create UUID
  set_fact:
    uuid: "{{ 99999 | random | to_uuid }}"

- name: Append UUID to file
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    dest: /dir/uuid.txt
    line: "{{ uuid }}"
    state: present
```

Is there a way to make this idempotent without stat or possibly adding a block? I am curious.

Comment: The term `{{ 99999 | random | to_uuid }}` will [generate every run a new random UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516011/), which is then not in the target file to append. Maybe you like to add an UUID only if there is no other UUID in the tartget file already?

Answer (score 2):

Use the module [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) if this is the single line in the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/uuid.txt
        content: |
          {{ 99999 | random | to_uuid }}
        force: false
```

To make it idempotent, set the parameter [*force*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-force) to *false*. Quoting:

> If false, the file will only be transferred if the destination does not exist.

Comment: Perfect! I did not see this parameter in ansibledoc. Thank you this works.